# MVCContrib grid - Can I specify tbody attributes?

Tags: knockout.js, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I'm trying to use MVCContrib grid together with [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/). To do this I have to specify data binding in tbody, e.g. `<tbody data-bind="foreach: people">`. I can't find the way how to do this.

`@Html.Grid(Model).Attributes()` applies my binding to `<table>` tag. Is there a way to set the `tbody` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **no, there is no way to set attributes on the `tbody`** with the current implementation.

**But you can implement this functionality by yourself:**

You just need to implement your own version of the `RenderBodyStart` mothod from the `GridRenderer` class.

There is alredy an implementation of the  `GridRenderer` called `HtmlTableGridRenderer` what you can build on:

```
public class BodyWithAttributesHtmlTableGridRenderer<T> 
    : HtmlTableGridRenderer<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string, object> bodyAttributes;

        public BodyWithAttributesHtmlTableGridRenderer(
            IDictionary<string, object> bodyAttributes)
        {
            this.bodyAttributes = bodyAttributes;
        }

        protected override void RenderBodyStart()
        {
            string str = BuildHtmlAttributes(bodyAttributes);
            if (str.Length > 0)
                str = " " + str;
            RenderText(string.Format("<tbody{0}>", str));
        }
    }
```

And in your view instead of calling  `Render()` you can use the `RenderUsing` method where you can specify your custom renderer:

```
@Html.Grid(Model))
    .RenderUsing(new BodyWithAttributesHtmlTableGridRenderer<MyModel>(
    new Dictionary<string, object>(){{"data-bind", "foreach: people"}}))
```

And the generated html will look something like this:

```
<table class="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Prop</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
        <tr class="gridrow">
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gridrow_alternate">
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You should note this is just a quick and dirty solution to show what is possible and there are more extension points what you can use to make the attribute passing more nicer.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I've found this link http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2010/06/12/render-mvccontrib-grid-with-no-header-row/ which explains the same solution that yours.